# How to create and verify user account when buying a product

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like to sell a product via Stripe on my website. When a user buys the product, I would like them to fill out a form with their email and password to create an account. I will then send this data to my own API which will insert their account into my database. How can I integrate this with Stripe?

Additionally, I need my API to be certain that that user did indeed purchase a product as only people who have purchased the product should have an account. How can I verify this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Another option is I allow anyone to sign up which I can do, and then when they purchase the product they enter their email. Then I send a request to my server to update the boolean value `activated` to be `True` for that email address if they did indeed purchase it. I think this is a better approach, but I still don't know how to make them give their email when purchasing the product or how I can verify that the user bought the product when sending the request to my API to update the boolean.

**EDIT2:** It seems like having an API is a bad idea. Instead, I will simply run the code to generate the user once they have submitted their payment. It seems like I can get their payment information and email using this API https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time, but how can I ask for their password and ensure that this is filled out for the payment to go through?

**EDIT3:** I now think the best approach is to create my own checkout form which will ask for their payment details as well as the password for their account. I will then send this information to my API via flask, which will send an API request to Stripe to process the payment. If their API responds saying the payment was a success, then I execute the code to add the user. If not, I tell the user it failed. What Stripe API should I be using to do this?

Comment: What language or framework are you using? You can have them enter their email, create payment, if payment successful, create account.  Email them and have them update their account with a password.  This can be done in one single form/payment in one or form then payment.

Comment: @uno Python/Flask. I'm not sure that's a good idea, how would I generate a secure one time only link?

Comment: @uno How about when I create the account I generate a salt and a random password, then I hash salt + password and store that in the database. Then I create a JWT using a hash of that hashed/salted password + the date of creation of the user as the secret key. Then when they click the link I update the hash in the database with the hash of the salt + new password  That way the link will only work once because their password will have changed.

Comment: @uno Although I still think the approach in my 3rd edit is better, I just can't work out how to do it. Although it would probably be better to use my own form + their payment form as mentioned in the comments of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've just about got your head around this - that's great.  It may still be easiest to have your own form that collects everything but the payment details, and then use Checkout to capture payment details.

You can either do this by [creating a Checkout Session server-side](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/one-time) - [with the email prefilled](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer_email) - or you can do [client-only Checkout with pre-filled email](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client#prefilling-customer-data) -along with webhooks - to make this happen.

Alternatively, you could use [Elements and Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web) - whatever makes more sense for your use situation.

Comment: I'm concerned about breaking up the forms as I might struggle to link the information in the initial form to the payment form. Any suggestions on how to do this cleanly and securely? I don't see why it would be very difficult to do what I suggested in my 3rd edit. From a brief look it seems like I can do that with payment intents. However, I am a bit concerned about custom verification checks etc from banks which I would not be able to process if I don't use Stripe's checkout form. So I'm leaning towards splitting the forms, but as mentioned I'm unsure of how to do this in practice.

Comment: I think I would like to create one page with both forms. The first form would be created by me and would allow the user to set their email and password, and the second form would be a standard Stripe checkout form. Then, I send all of this information to my server to process. On the server I process the Stripe form and if the payment is successful, I add the user to my database using their provided email and password. I'm not sure how to achieve this though.

Comment: That's fine, you can do that.  Just use Elements in your form/client side and Payment Intents server side (in the link I provided) to do so.  Don't collect the card details in your form and then send them to your server, use Elements for that.